# Relationship between cardinality of abelian group and ring in module

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules

I was hoping someone could verify (or provide a counterexample) the following claim:

> Let $R$ be a ring. Let $V$ be an abelian group, so that $V$ forms an $R$- module. If $ |R| < |V|$, then $V$ is not a $R$- module (or atmost trivial).

I know this to be true for $\mathbb{Z}^n$ -modules, but I am not sure whether this is true in general. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true, even your statement about $\mathbb Z^n$ is not true. Any finite abelian group, e.g. $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module in a natural way, but of course $|\mathbb Z|$ is much greater than $|\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z|$.

If $R$ is a domain and you add the words "torsion-free" then it becomes true so long as $V$ is nontrivial, because then if you fix some $v\in V$, the map $r\mapsto rv$ from $R$ to $V$ is an injection.

Comment: Moreover, it's probably only true if you assume everything in sight is unital, otherwise we have the trivial module structures.